# Using $or clause in pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have these fields in a collection:

```
[{
     u'_id': ObjectId('4d1f7b4d5d256b18c8000000'),
     u'name': u'1'
 },{
     u'_id': ObjectId('4d1f7b505d256b18c8000001'),
     u'name': u'2'
 },{
     u'_id': ObjectId('4d1f7b525d256b18c8000002'),
     u'name': u'3'
 }]
```

Then I make a query like this:

```
 [x for x in c.things.find( {'$or' : [{'name':'1'}, {'name':'2'}] } )]
```

and I expect to get:

```
[{
    u'_id': ObjectId('4d1f7b4d5d256b18c8000000'),
    u'name': u'1'
}, {
    u'_id': ObjectId('4d1f7b505d256b18c8000001'),
    u'name': u'2'
}]
```

Unfortunately not. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using mongodb from the ubuntu repository which is older than 1.5.3 (The documentation of mongodb says that $or is available from 1.5.3).
After I changed to the latest release (1.6.5) everything is working as expected.

Comment: Upvote: Same thing just happened to me.  I know it's a silly thing to upvote on, but sometimes you're banging your head against the wall and you just need a post like this to remind yourself to check the basic things... like version numbers.